# wsl2で chmod usr1:usr1 file で invalid mode: 'usr1:usr1' エラーで変更できません

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, wsl-2

### 行いたいこと

root:root のファイルをusr1へファイル所有者、グループを変更したい。

### 現象

wsl2でユーザー名とグループ名を変更するために `sudo chmod usr1:usr1 file` を実行すると`chmod: invalid mode: 'usr1:usr1'` エラーで変更できません。

### 行った操作

PowerShell管理者権限で`wsl --install -d Ubuntu`してインストール。

```
PS C:\Users\admin> wsl -l -v
  NAME      STATE           VERSION
* Ubuntu    Running         2
```

以下Ubuntuターミナルにて操作

```
:
Enter new UNIX username: usr1
:
usr1@pc:~$ sudo su -
root@pc:~# cd ../home/usr1
root@pc:/home/usr1# echo abc > file
root@pc:/home/usr1# exit

usr1@pc:~$ ls -l
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4 Dec  4 21:49 file

usr1@pc:~$ sudo chmod 777 file
usr1@pc:~$ ls -l
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Dec  4 21:49 file

usr1@pc:~$ sudo chmod usr1:usr1 file
chmod: invalid mode: ‘usr1:usr1’
Try 'chmod --help' for more information
```

Ubuntuをアンインストール、再インストールを何度行っても同じ現象です。
間違った操作があるとのではないかと思います。
ご指摘のほどよろしくお願いいたします。

### 環境

Windows 10 Pro 22H2
Windows 11 Home 22H2
※ 両方とも同じ現象です。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ファイルの所有者を変更するには [`chown`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/ja/man1/chown.1.html) コマンドを使用してください。
([`chmod`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/ja/man1/chmod.1.html) はファイルの権限 = パーミッションを変更するコマンドです)

> #### 名前
>
> chown - ファイルの所有者とグループを変更する
>
> #### 書式
>
> ```
> chown [OPTION]... [OWNER][:[GROUP]] FILE...
> ```

Comment: ありがとうございました。

Comment: 検索でchmod での説明があったので鵜呑みににしておりました。